# admin create product, custom attribute validation limit to choose number between

Tags: magento-1.8, product-attribute, validation, create-product

I have custom product attribute called **Donation**, I created it by

```
Catelog->Attribute->Manage-Attribute   Add New Attribute.
```

Their is no problem, Its working fine, But I need to add validation for this fields,

while creating product admin should give number from 20 to 100, I am mentioning percentage here and 20 is the minimum donation percentage,

I am not able to do this, help me, How to validate this? or **how can I restrict the admin to choose number between 20 to 100**,?
Thanks in Advance:)

Comment: you can add custom validation in validation.js file in js/prototype.and add class to your input

Comment: you can follow this link.
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15163/custom-form-validation-magento

Comment: @sivakumar, I created this custom attribute by Manage-Attribute, How Can I Add class to select in backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option that would not involve any custom code would be to make this option a select field and then add all the option values from 20-100. Sure it may not be the prettiest option but would work nicely.

If you wanted to not have to add all the options to the attribute you could create this attribute and set a source model. In this source model you can then populate the select and not have to add all the options yourself.

Simply setup your attribute in a setup script with the source model

```
$setup->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'custom_select', array(
    'input' => 'select',
    'type' => 'int',
    'label' => 'Custom Select',
    'visible' => 1,
    'required' => 0,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'source' => 'mymodule/selectoptions',
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
));
```

And then add your source model code.

```
class Mypackage_Mymodule_Model_Selectoptions extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract {

    public function getAllOptions($withEmpty = true)
    {
        // This code could be done in a for loop :)
        $options = array(
            array('label' => '20', 'value' => 20),
            array('label' => '21', 'value' => 21),
            array('label' => '22', 'value' => 22),
            array('label' => '23', 'value' => 23),
            ....
        );
        if ($withEmpty) {
            array_unshift($options, array('label' => '', 'value' => ''));
        }

        return $options;
    }
}
```