# Validate input field that contains only number or letter

Tags: validation

I need to validate my input field that need to contain only number or letter, not both of them. For example:

> 13131 or LosAngeles are valid.
>
> Los131 is invalid

Here is my form:

```
<form id="search-form" method="post" action="">
  <lebel>Search For</label>
  <input type="text" class=""/>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var searchForm = new VarienForm('search-form');
</script>
```

How can I do that ? I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native validation class available in magento validation lib.

Use this below code

```
Validation.add('validate-test','your message for validation error',function(v){
    return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || (!isNaN(parseNumber(v)) && /^\s*-?\d*(\.\d*)?\s*$/.test(v)) || /^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(v);
});
```

Add this script in your js file.

[Refer This Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15163/custom-form-validation-magento)

Comment: How to validate like accept number with any one special characters in phone field

Answer (score 1):

use this class in your input field

```
class = "validate-alpha" -- > Character only
class = "validate-number" -- > Number Only
```

For more refer `http://inchoo.net/magento/out-of-the-box-form-validation-in-magento/`